# Error XDG0008: NumberBox is not supported in a Universal Windows Platform project

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visual-studio-2019

There is a strange problem with the following code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="FuckNumberBox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FuckNumberBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <NumberBox x:Name="BeginNumberBox"
                   Header="Enter an integer:" 
                   Value="1" 
                   SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact" 
                   SmallChange="10"
                   LargeChange="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image: IDE Screenshot]

After creating the project, no changes were made until I added the `<NumberBox>`. There will be raised three compilation errors:

[image: Error message]

I try update NuGet Package:

[image: NuGet Package Manager]

But the error still here.

How can I repair this?

I could really need some help here :/

---

Development environment:

- IDE: Visual Studio 2019

  UWP project target version: Windows 10, version 1903(10.0; Build
  18362)

  UWP project min version: Windows 10, version 1903(10.0; Build 18362)

Comment: add WinUI package [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/nuget-packages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.NumberBox?view=winui-2.3) of NumberBox, you can see that the NumberBox is under the **Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls** namespace and applies to WinUI. So as @magicandre1981 said, you need to install [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml) nuget package and add the Windows UI (WinUI) Theme Resources to your App.xaml resources. Then add the namespace in xaml to use it.

App.xaml:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="FuckNumberBox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FuckNumberBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">

    <Grid>
        <controls:NumberBox x:Name="BeginNumberBox"
                   Header="Enter an integer:" 
                   Value="1" 
                   SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact" 
                   SmallChange="10"
                   LargeChange="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the customControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="GroceryPriceTracker.Controls.NumberBoxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:GroceryPriceTracker.Controls"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="CWidth">35</x:Double>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Height="{StaticResource CWidth}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox InputScope="Number" BorderThickness="1"
                 Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"
                 Padding="10,6,10,0"
                 Height="35"
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleBlack}"></TextBox>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              BorderBrush="{ThemeResource InkToolbarAccentColorThemeBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Width="{StaticResource CWidth}"
              Height="{StaticResource CWidth}">
            <Button Width="{StaticResource CWidth}"
                    Height="{StaticResource CWidth}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <FontIcon FontSize="17"
                          FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                          Glyph="&#xE010;" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2"
              Margin="-5,0,0,0"
              BorderBrush="{ThemeResource InkToolbarAccentColorThemeBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Width="{StaticResource CWidth}"
              Height="{StaticResource CWidth}">
            <Button Width="{StaticResource CWidth}"
                    Height="{StaticResource CWidth}"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Grid.Column="2">
                <FontIcon FontSize="17"
                          FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                          Glyph="&#xE09D;" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```